# Не работает обработчик нажатия клавиши в jQuery

Tags: jquery, keydown

Необходимо чтобы при наведении на определенный блок срабатывал обработчик нажатия на стрелки вниз и вверх, но чет не пойму как это реализовать.

[Вот пример](https://jsfiddle.net/9r8LLv01/71/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div.test').on('mouseover', function() {

    $('div.test').html('Навели курсор на блок');
    $('div.test').bind('keydown', function(e) {         
      switch(e.keyCode) {
        case 38:
        $('div.test').html('Стрелка вверх');
        break;
        case 40:
        $('div.test').html('Стрелка вниз');
        break;
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Немного поковырял и получилось реализовать таким образом (правда не знаю насколько это корректно)

[Рабочий пример](https://jsfiddle.net/9r8LLv01/97/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в том, что в js нет такого события, чтобы при наведении на конкретный объект сработала проверка на нажатие клавиши. Если же это не input, textarea или div с атрибутом contenteditable=true.

Если тебе нужно, чтобы событие клавиш работало при наведении на объект, то так:

```
$('.test').mouseover(function() {
    $('.test').html('Навели курсор на блок');
    document.onkeydown = function(event) {
        if(event.keyCode == 38) {$('.test').html('Стрелка вверх');}
        if(event.keyCode == 40) {$('.test').html('Стрелка вниз');}
    };
});

$('.test').mouseleave(function() {
    $('.test').html('Убрали курсор с блока');
    document.onkeydown = null;
});
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное )